# Running another ruby script with globals intact?

Tags: ruby

For reasons that are a little hard to explain, I need to do the following: I have a `master.rb` file that sets some global like: `a = 1`.  I want to call another file `other_file.rb` that will run with the globals that were set in the master file.  In python I'd use `runpy.run_module( 'other_module', globals() )`.

Can anyone think of an equivalent in Ruby?  I've looked at `require`, `include`, and `load`, but none seem to do quite what I need, specifically they don't pull the globals into the `other_file.rb`.  Note that I am not trying to fork a new process, just hand execution over to "other_module" while maintaining the state of the globals.

Comment: That is not a global. `$a = 1` is setting a global. You are just setting a local variable in the outer scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a=1` is not a global variable, it is a local variable that gets scoped to the file. If you really nee this behavior, use `$a=1` to set global variables.

Comment: Thank you, that was the critical piece I was missing!

Answer (score 4):

If you *absolutely must*, you can use globals, and they're declared with the `$` prefix. They are highly discouraged because there is only one global namespace, which makes collisions possible. Generally they are used for interpreter configuration, like `$LOAD_PATH`.

A better approach is to use a module that has instance variables:

```
module MyContainer
  def self.settings
    @settings ||= { }
  end
end

MyContainer.settings[:foo] = :bar
```

This has the advantage of keeping your variables contained in a namespace while not preventing other sub-programs from accessing them.

Keep in mind this will only work within the context of the same Ruby process or children created using `fork`, so using `system` or `exec` will not work. Remember also that forked processes need to use IPC to communicate with their parent.

Comment: I agree that's a clean way.  In the very weird circumstance that I'm in it won't work though.  Thanks for the explanation!